# Bash: convert line to array while keeping consecutive spaces in items

Tags: arrays, bash, line, whitespace

There have been plenty of posts about how to convert a line into an array in Bash. I did not find one that answered my question: how does one do the conversion when items can have consecutive spaces and you don't want those collapsed into a single character?

Example input line: `a bcd "ef gh" "   ijk   "`

Expected array items: `"a", "bcd", "ef gh", "   ijk   "`

So the last one should NOT be `" ijk "`, which is the result when using the standard `arr=$(line)` solution.

It is acceptable to me when consecutive whitespace characters between the arguments in the input line are collapsed.

The example is really just an example. The input line will be read from file containing many different lines to be converted.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `bash` doesn't have a good way of parsing such a line. I would suggest modifying the input file to store each array element on a separate line, and adding a special marker between groups of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially contradicting my comment, if you modify your input file to look like

```
a bcd ef\ gh \ \ \ ijk\ \ \
```

then

```
while read -a arr; do
    printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
done < file.txt
```

would preserve the escaped spaces the way you want. (Without `-r`, `read` will only peform word splitting on the unescaped spaces.) Unlike normal shell processing, `"ef gh"` here is not equivalent to `ef\ gh`.

---

The solution I referred to in my comment would be a more heavily modified input file:

```
a
bcd
ef gh
   ijk   
#
l m
n op
#
q r s
  tu v
```

and a loop like

```
while :; do
    arr=()
    while IFS= read -r element; do
        if [[ element = #* ]]; then
            # do something with arr here
            break
        fi
        arr+=("$element")
    done
done < file.txt
```

Comment: thanks! It isn't entirely what I was hoping for but it works. If it can't be done any easier then that's the way it is...